# Происхождение и значение современного употребления "погнали"

Tags: лексикон, этимология

Хотел бы сверить с обществом собственные социокультурные соображения по поводу выражения *погнали* в значении *начали*. Откуда оно есть пошло?

Пример употребления глагола "погнать" в значении "начать что-либо делать":

> Когда все актеры были готовы, а играющие в первой сцене заняли свои места, кто-то крикнул "Ну, погнали!".

Глагол в таком значении употребляется только в разговорной речи и только в повелительном наклонении.

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить пример или ситуацию описать.

Comment: Пример из кинофильма"бумер": "погнали, поцаны!."

Comment: Это не формальность, ваш вопрос может быть интересен людям, не знающим русского, а далеко не всякий словарь дает перевод слова "погнать" в этом значении. Поэтому описание значения слова бывает полезно. С вашего позволения, я добавлю толкование в пост.

Comment: Аналогично "по коням", "запрягай", "придержи лошадей". Ассоциация любого дела с поездкой вполне нормальна

Comment: Мне больше интересно откуда пошло разговорное значение `гнать` как `сойти с ума`,`врать`. Например, `ты что, гонишь?`, `не гони`.

Comment: Я думаю, что "гнать" в этом смысле означает, что человек совсем разогнался в своём вранье. "И тут Остапа понесло".

Comment: @Yurij73, действительно, отредактируйте, пожалуйста, сам вопрос, добавив значение, которое вы имеете ввиду. Комментарий дело хорошое, но вопрос должен быть самодостаточным. Кроме того, "Погнали, пацаны!" - плохой пример для неносителей, например.

Answer (score 10):

По-видимому, речь идёт об употреблении этого глагола в значении «поехали», «начали». Полагаю, что оно происходит от «гнать лошадей», т.е. быстро ехать.

Answer (score 1):

"Погнали" в значении перешли к какому-то совместному действию, скорее всего, но не обязательно, сопряжённому с физическим перемещением участников этого действия употребляется относительно редко и с относительно недавнего времени. В прозе 30-х гг. прошлого века, к примеру, таких примеров мало (и я буду благодарен за такую цитату в принципе).

Тем не менее, возможно, что слово встречается редко по причине схожей с той, по которой, например, слово "охренеть" не встречается на страницах классиков.

"погнали" в смежном, переходном значении - пошли вместе куда-то (причём без внешнего принуждения), например, есть у Ивана Сергеевича Шмелёва в рассказе "Небывалый обед":

> Затребовал льду корзину, дрова, чтобы без сучка, березовых... такой леестр прописал -- половины в Охотном не достали, к Андрееву погнали, на Тверскую.

Ещё один намёк/подсказка на то, откуда слово погнали приобрело то значение, о котором вы спрашиваете, есть у Николая Алексеевича Некрасова. В поэме "Кому на Руси жить хорошо". Вот описание охоты:

> Стоял помещик сам \ А там, в лесу, выжлятники \ Ревели, сорвиголовы, \
>   Варили варом гончие. \ Чу! подзывает рог!.. \ Чу! стая воет!
>   сгрудилась \ Никак, по зверю красному \ Погнали?.. улю-лю!

То есть зверя гнали. И можно представить как один охотник говорит другому: "Ну что, погнали?".